# Docker image build failed with error "Operation not permitted"

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am getting docker image build error "Operation not permitted". `chmod 777 R  /PredictionIO-0.14.0/lib/spark/`  did not solve it.

I am trying to create PredictionIO docker image through git CICD to run in K8t

`pio build --verbose`

```
    [INFO] DOCKER> [91mls: cannot access '/PredictionIO-0.14.0/lib/spark/pio-data-elasticsearch-assembly-0.14.0.jar': Operation not permitted ls: cannot access '/PredictionIO-0.14.0/lib/spark/pio-data-hbase-assembly-0.14.0.jar': Operation not permitted
    
     [INFO] DOCKER> [91mls: cannot access '/PredictionIO-0.14.0/lib/spark/pio-data-hdfs-assembly-0.14.0.jar': Operation not permitted
    ls: cannot access '/PredictionIO-0.14.0/lib/spark/pio-data-jdbc-assembly-0.14.0.jar': Operation not permitted
    ls: cannot access '/PredictionIO-0.14.0/lib/spark/pio-data-localfs-assembly-0.14.0.jar': Operation not permitted
    ls: cannot access '/PredictionIO-0.14.0/lib/spark/pio-data-s3-assembly-0.14.0.jar': Operation not permitted
    [INFO] DOCKER> [91mError: Could not find or load main class org.apache.predictionio.tools.console.Console
    [INFO] DOCKER> Removing intermediate container 8c164b439d1b
    [ERROR] DOCKER> Unable to build image [myimage/bellmedia-pio-0.14.0:latest] : "The command '/bin/sh -c pio build --verbose' returned a non-zero code: 1"  ["The command '/bin/sh -c pio build --verbose' returned a non-zero code: 1" ]
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8
MAINTAINER Jhon

ARG HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxyServer:8083/
ARG HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxyServer:8083/


ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN export http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} \
    && export https_proxy=${HTTPS_PROXY} \
    && apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y net-tools curl patch gawk g++ gcc make libc6-dev vim telnet bash patch libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgdbm-dev  libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison pkg-config libffi-dev libffi-dev krb5-user libpam-krb5 libpam-ccreds python3-pip tini libc6 libpam-modules libnss3 cron
    

ENV PIO_VERSION 0.14.0
ENV SPARK_VERSION 2.4.4
ENV ELK_VERSION 5.6.9
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.11.12
ENV HBASE_VERSION 1.0.0
ENV HADOOP_VERSION 2.7
ENV PIO_GIT_URL  http://archive.apache.org/dist/predictionio/

ENV PIO_HOME /PredictionIO-${PIO_VERSION}
ENV PATH=${PIO_HOME}/bin:/PredictionIO-0.14.0/vendors/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin:$PATH
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/local/openjdk-8

EXPOSE 9200 9300
RUN export http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} \
    && export https_proxy=${HTTPS_PROXY} \
    && curl -O https://archive.apache.org/dist/predictionio/${PIO_VERSION}/apache-predictionio-${PIO_VERSION}.tar.gz

RUN mkdir predictionio

RUN tar -zxf apache-predictionio-${PIO_VERSION}.tar.gz -C /predictionio \
    && rm apache-predictionio-${PIO_VERSION}.tar.gz

COPY sbt-launch.jar /root/.sbt/launchers/1.2.3/
WORKDIR /predictionio

RUN export http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} \
    && export https_proxy=${HTTPS_PROXY} \
    && ./make-distribution.sh -Dscala.version=${SCALA_VERSION} -Dspark.version=${SPARK_VERSION} -Delasticsearch.version=${ELK_VERSION}

WORKDIR /
RUN tar -zxvf predictionio/PredictionIO-${PIO_VERSION}.tar.gz \
    && rm predictionio/PredictionIO-${PIO_VERSION}.tar.gz

COPY pio-env.sh ${PIO_HOME}/conf/
COPY log4j.properties ${PIO_HOME}/conf/

RUN mkdir ${PIO_HOME}/vendors

WORKDIR ${PIO_HOME}/vendors
RUN export http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} \
    && export https_proxy=${HTTPS_PROXY} \
    && curl -O  https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz

RUN tar -zxvf spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz \
    && rm spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz

COPY spark-defaults.conf spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}/conf/

WORKDIR ${PIO_HOME}
RUN export http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} \
    && export https_proxy=${HTTPS_PROXY} \
    && mkdir URM \
    && cd URM \
    && git clone https://github.com/actionml/universal-recommender.git

COPY build.sbt /PredictionIO-0.14.0/URM/universal-recommender/
COPY engine.json /PredictionIO-0.14.0/URM/universal-recommender/
RUN rm -rf target
RUN ln -s /PredictionIO-0.14.0/vendors/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/ /opt/spark
WORKDIR ${PIO_HOME}/URM/universal-recommender/
RUN mkdir lib

COPY sbt-launch.jar /root/.sbt/launchers/0.13.13/

RUN export SBT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy.ca -Dhttp.proxyPort=8083 -Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy.ca -Dhttps.proxyPort=8083"
RUN chmod 777 -R /PredictionIO-0.14.0/lib/spark/

###########################  Command below is failing ##################

RUN export http_proxy=${HTTP_PROXY} \
    && export https_proxy=${HTTPS_PROXY} \
    && pio build --verbose 

CMD ["sh", "-c", "tail -f /dev/null"]
```

Any suggestion is highly applicated.
Thanks
Jhon

Comment: Please share the Dockerfile

Comment: added docker file

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [mcve]?  If you remove three or four of the package installations before this, does the problem still happen?